# How to force volume mount refresh on Kubernetes docker

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

I am using the Kubernetes deployment on local Docker VM (MacOs) To develop.

Instead of creating a new image and killing the pod for each code change iteration I mount the code From the IDE into the docker

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata: 
  name: monitor-storage
  namespace: wielder-services
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata: 
  name: monitor-pvc
  namespace: wielder-services
  labels: 
    app: monitor
spec: 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources: 
    requests: 
      storage: 200Mi
  storageClassName: monitor-storage
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata: 
  name: monitor-pv
spec: 
  capacity: 
    storage: 200Mi
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: monitor-storage
  local: 
    path: /<path to code folder>
  nodeAffinity: 
    required: 
      nodeSelectorTerms: 
        - 
          matchExpressions: 
            - 
              key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values: 
                - docker-desktop
```

This works fine and I used to immediately see changes in the IDE file in the pod shell and vice versa. Now I cant view changes in the IDE even if I delete and re-deploy the entire volume deployment combination. It seems the directory content is copied to a different place in cache or storage.

following a few threads I stopped the IDE to see if there is an effect but the changes in the files don't appear in the mounted directory.

according to documentation this should be possible:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#file-sharing

Is there a way to force a remounting of the host(MacOs) Directory?

Comment: Kubernetes isn't really suitable as a live-development environment.  Note that you've probably written more YAML to try to make live reloading work than the rest of your deployment setup, and you'll need to rip this out again if you want to deploy to a "real" cluster.  I tend to use a non-container local development environment for most work; plain Docker if I need to work out packaging issues, and Kubernetes only for final integration testing and deployment.

Comment: @D Kubernetes did it just fine up till now